# How to adjust a thermostatic shower cartridge?

Tags: shower, hot-water

I changed the thermostatic cartridge in my shower and I am struggling to calibrate it so that the temperature is comfortable, and the temperature control is logical.

It looks like this, which is a Bristan 00622415

[image: Bristan Screw-In Brass Thermo Cartridge - 00622415]

I watched youtube videos, and it seems as simple as turning it clockwise as much as possible until the water is cold, and then turning it back 1 quarter anti-clockwise turns until the water is at a comfortable temperature.

When I try this the water jumps from cold to boiling hot event at a 1 quarter turn, and doesn't seem to gradually get hot as I would expect.

Any advice?

Comment: Is there any point at which the temperature is comfortable? If so, the manual indicates you should make that the max temp by installing the handle so it cannot turn beyond that point. If not, the cartridge may be defective.